# Visual Basic cannot using form when coding

Tags: vb.net

I have a form called "cancel reservation", so when i try to calling this form in my coding , it cannot be call.

Please check my attachment here
I can using call for all other form but not this one, can anyone please give some advise?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form's name is most likely just `Cancel_Reservation` instead of `formCancel_Reservation` (that is, if you've not renamed it of course).

For example:

```
Cancel_Reservation.Close()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Why the downvote? Could the downvoter at least leave a comment to why this answer was not so great? It is likely to answer the OP's question, and there's not much more detail to add... -- Either way I have edited the answer a little, in hope of making you a little more happy about it. :>

Answer (score 0):

Use show() function to call forms.If your form name is Cancel_reservartion then call like this,

```
Cancel_reservartion .show()
```

Just try it.